# Creating Debug Window for WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, debugging

I am creating a WPF App and one problem my team always faces is debugging problems in a Client PC that doesn't have Visual Studio installed. So I want to create a sort of "SafeMode" or "DebugMode" Window. Basically what this would do is type up all events, errors, etc that can be usefull to the developer using the Client PC.

This window will only be called if needed, and once open it should be able to recieve data from all other windows in the application. I am not looking to type up the errors and events by hand, but I am wondering if there is some .Net Function that does that for me?

I guess similra to the Output Dialog in VS2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debugging problems in a Client PC => either make sure your application logs everything that is of importance (to a log file will do, no need for a window), or in the extreme you could run the VS Remote Debug Monitor and connect to it using VS, in which case it would be like debugging the app in your own pc. That last one needs a network connection to the client's pc though, so I'd go with option one. And possibly more unit tests to begin with, which leads to less bugs hence less debugging needed.

Comment: Thanks stijn, this we are doing. Only two problems, 1) it writes everything into XML 2) it slows performance noticably. Microsoft even states that we should select only what we need due to performance issues. My plan was to throw all Logs into a RichTextBox instead of an xml log file, which should not result in performance loss.

Comment: logging to screen might be slower than to a file; if logging really is a bottleneck, put the actual logging in a seperate thread that takes log events from a queue. The rest of the application logs by putting events on the queue, you won't get much faster logging than that.

Comment: alright. not exactly what I'm looking for but guess its good enough for the programmers to figure out what whent wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Usually application logs all internal events in file (txt, xml, etc). If some errors occurred then application reports about it to user and sends current log and error (with all exception's information such as stack trace) to developers. 
Additional function - the button to take screenshot add comment and send to developers...
In your case, if developers can use client's pc you may install visual studio remote debugger and debug applications via network...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a logging block like log4net http://logging.apache.org/log4net/
This allows you to log at different levels, e.g. debug, info, error, fatal.

You can get a list of features here.
http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/features.html

Comment: my question is specific to WPF, how does apache play a role into this?

Comment: log4net is a logging framework for .net (it runs on windows). You could alternatively use the logging application block or just write to your own text files.